# Filter a numpy ndarray using another numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have two numpy ndarrays of the same shape `(15081, 56724, 3, 3)`. What I want to do is as follows:

Say we have a cross section of the first array, `array1[1, 1, :, :]`, looks like this:

```
[[120, 110, 220],
 [ 85,  99,  72],
 [197,  80,  75]]
```

I want to convert it to a boolean in a way that the max of each row is `True` and the rest is `False`. In the whole array, this corresponds to `axis=3`. So the array looks like this after conversion:

```
[[False, False,  True],
 [False,  True, False],
 [ True, False, False]]
```

Now I want to filter the other array, `array2`, using this boolean array to have something that looks like below. I only want to keeping those values of `array2` that correspond to `True` in `array1` and set the rest to zero.

```
[[  0,   0,  65],
 [  0, 179,   0],
 [125,   0,   0]]
```

I can do this using a loop but it takes an age (even more).
I expect something like `numpy.where(array1.is_max(axis=3), True, False)`, but there is no function like `is_max` in python, besides this way the axis 3 is collapsed and I cannot filter `array2` using `array1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In numpy, `is_max` is approximately [`argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```
indices = array1.argmax(axis=-1)
```

Instead of a mask, this will give you a linear index, so you can do

```
array2b = np.zeros_like(array2)
index = np.indices(array2.shape[:-1], sparse=True) + (indices,)
array2b[index] = array1[index]
```

You can do something similar with [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) and [`np.put_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html):

```
indices = np.expand_dims(array1.argmax(-1), array1.ndim - 1)
array2b = np.zeros_like(array2)
np.put_along_axis(array2b, indices, np.take_along_axis(array2, indices, -1), -1)
```

If you want a mask-based approach, you can create the mask like this:

```
mask = array1 != array1.max(-1, keepdims=True)
```

Now you can set all elements to zero directly:

```
array2[mask] = 0
```

Alternatively you can do something like

```
mask = array1 == array1.max(-1, keepdims=True)
array2 *= mask
```

**Update**

From your description in the comments, you are looking for a different operation entirely. You can start by thresholding `array1` (which I assume represents the difference between the blurred and original image):

```
mask = array1 >= 100  # find a threshold that works
array2 *= mask
```

OR

```
mask = array1 < 100
array2[mask] = 0
```

You may also be looking for local minima in an image. You can get those by finding pixels that are bigger than their surroundings. To do that, run a non-linear filter on the image, like [`scipy.ndimage.maximum_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.maximum_filter.html):

```
 mask = array1 == scipy.ndimage.maximum_filter(array1, 5)
 array2 *= mask
```

Comment: Thanks for your solutions, they worked perfectly but my original problem (not mentioned here) remained unsolved. I wanna do focus stacking of 3 large z-stack layers. I already tried available functions and using freeware from inside python. But either the quality of output was bad or they took an age. What I tried here was to calculate the blurred pixels of each layer and find the difference with the original layers. The larger the difference, the sharper the original pixel. Then as you suggested I create mask from the diff matrix and .... But there are many missing pixels in output image.

Comment: @SinaALizadeh. You should ask a separate question about that. It's not something I can answer without seeing concrete data, and certainly not within the scope of a comment. I would recommend finding a small region that encapsulates a missing pixel, and trying to isolate which steps cause a discrepancy. Ping me if you end up with a question, although I suspect you will end up solving your issue once you inspect the data more closely.

Comment: @SinaALizadeh. Also, don't forget to accept the answer so your question can be removed from the unanswered queue.

Comment: @SinaALizadeh. Now that I think about it, you probably want to threshold the data, not search for the maxima. Your mask should be `array1 > 100` or so, not `arrayy == array1.max(-1, keepdims=True)`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Here is where I asked somehow my problem. There is a link to original data
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68188852/python-subprocess-mix-up-the-output-of-different-processes

Comment: Thanks @Mad Physicist. I opened a new question. I will really appreciate your help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68768212/how-to-focus-stack-images-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with

```
array2[array1 != np.tile(np.max(array1,axis=1), (array1.shape[0],1)).T] = 0
```

Here is how.

For your particular example, i would suggest to use `np.tile`,  where you can create a repeating pattern out of the elements in your 1-D mask.

Suppose we have your matrix a with values

```
array1 = [[120, 110, 220]
          [85, 99, 72]
          [197, 80, 75]]
```

Then the maximum values in every row of your matrix would be

```
maxes = np.max(array1,axis=1)
```

which will have the values

```
array([220,  99, 197])
```

now, what we need is to use each of these values in each row per each row element. Simply put, we need to compare 220 with each element in the first row. This means that actually we need to repeat the value 220, to be able to perform the operation in a single vector, which can be done with:

```
np.tile(maxes, (array1.shape[0],1)).T
```

which gives us

```
array([[220, 220, 220],
       [ 99,  99,  99],
       [197, 197, 197]])
```

filtering is rather straightforward:

```
a != np.tile(maxes, (3,1)).T
```

is sufficient to create the mask.

**Long story short, the operation can be done in a single liner as following**:

```
array2[array1 != np.tile(maxes, (a.shape[0],1)).T] = 0
```

which enables a to have following values

```
array2 = array([[0, 0, 65]
                [0, 179, 0]
                [125, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: You don't need to tile since broadcasting does that for you more efficiently

Comment: I see. I will read your answer more carefully then.